# Windows 10 BSOD and shutdowns ntoskrnl.exe

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, bsod, crash

I am getting several bluescreens in windows that all seem to be memory related such as SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION and irql_not_less_or_equal.  I checked the minidump with bluescreenview and it appears that the common denominator between all of these crashes is ntoskrnl.exe (the last 10 crashes have all been caused by this).  here are the 2 latest dump files: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1aouW88E8jBUFd4cWJNOUM0YmM&usp=sharing

I am starting to suspect hardware fault though as I reinstalled windows to no effect and sometimes, instead of bluescreening, the computer simply shuts off, immediately and without warning.

Here are my specs:
GTX 1070 ZOTAC AMP EXTREME
fx 8350
corsair AX760 PSU
16GB of 1866 MHZ hyperx fury ram

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running a memory test to see if that's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that one of the ram slots in my motherboard, when filled,causes this error.  Not sure why but for now I am just using 12gb of ram.  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: ok, good to see that you found the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the [KHX1866C10D3/4G RAM on the supported RAM list](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97_R20/HelpDesk_QVL/) for your ASUS M5A97 R2.0 motherboard. This may cause stability issues.

You may also OC your CPU:

```
CP  F/M/S  Manufacturer     MHz
 6 21,2,0  AuthenticAMD    4335
```

The AMD FX 8350 only runs at 4GHz, so lower the speed and look if the PC is stable again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! turns out that it was the motherboard.  I removed two of my sticks of ram and found that it now works perfectly.  I tested them in the other slots and found that the ram is fine but one of those slots on the mobo seems to be having issues.  I will continue to investigate further into the root cause of this but I think I can live with only 12GB of ram :)  btw, i tried lowering the oc and it had no effect but thanks for the suggestion